# Naive Bayes for two continuous features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

I have two features which are both continuous. How to perform a classification task based on them? I've read the Wikipedia entry on [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier), but this is only for discrete outcome and one feature.

Comment: What is the outcome you want to classify?

Comment: The outcome is discrete class (nominal).

Comment: Err, actually, not.  The wikipedia page labels the features $F_1\ldots F_n$.

Comment: @fkr Does this question/answer help ?: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4298/use-of-kernel-density-estimate-in-naive-bayes-classifier

Comment: @ConjugatePrior Does it mean `P(C).P(F1|C).P(F2|C)` rather than `P(C).P(F|C)`?

Comment: @steffen Actually I don't understand... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution in [the same page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Testing). It might because I was dumb or being stressed :).

Example:

$$
\text{posterior}(\text{male})=\frac{P(\text{male})P(\text{height}\mid\text{male})P(\text{weight}\mid\text{male})P(\text{footsize}\mid\text{male})}{\text{evidence}}
$$

Thanks @ConjugatePrior.

Comment: Glad to hear it now makes sense.  btw you don't have to post the image - you can write it in latex math notation, e.g. Bayes theorem is written `p(C|F) = \frac{p(F|C) p(C)}{p(F)}` which when you surround it with `$` signs renders automatically as $p(C|F) = \frac{p(F|C) p(C)}{p(F)}$.

Comment: @fkr so, concluding from your answer your actual question was how to perform NB with more than one feature ? I ask because your answer does not aim at the special case of continuous features ;). Some have problems calculating the conditional probabilities for cont. features, so I thought your question aims in the same direction.

Comment: @steffen Actually, I need simply two numerical features and a class of nominal :).

Comment: To point out a nuance about BornToCode's answer, the expression he wrote for the probability of a class is not technically correct. For continuous features such as height, the conditional probability of a single value is always 0. Fortunately, we can use the height of the conditional probability density function corresponding to the value of height as a proxy for the conditional probability of that value occurring. See [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136577/how-to-deal-with-mixture-of-continuous-and-discrete-features-when-using-naive-ba/147535#147535) for more details.