# Real values in Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier

Tags: python, naive-bayes, scikit-learn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Naive Bayes for two continuous features](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/naive-bayes-for-two-continuous-features)

I've seen that Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier in [Sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) accepts real valued feature vectors.

I previously assumed that Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier only handles discrete values

If I were to design a multinomial Naive Bayes classifier of my own, how would I handle real valued feature vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is by "binning" -- the domain of the real value is binned into a finite set of intervals, and then each example is placed at the relevant bin.

You can read more about it in the following Wikipedia page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier

starting at "Another common ..."