# Regarding kernel-based naive Bayesian classifier

Tags: machine-learning, references, naive-bayes, kernel-smoothing

Are there any good references for kernel-based Naive Bayesian classifier?

Comment: as far as I know, a kernel based NB is just a Naive Bayes which uses kernels to approximate the pdf of continuous variables, meanwhile "default" NB assumes a normal distribution (or make the data discrete beforehand). In this spirit, is the paper linked in this question/answer sufficient ? [Use of kernel density estimate in Naive Bayes Classifier?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4298/use-of-kernel-density-estimate-in-naive-bayes-classifier)

Comment: or, to be more precise, I have the slight feeling that your question is a duplicate of the linked one. Do you agree on this ?